# How to make a HRMP channel between two parachains in mock.rs?

Tags: parachain, hrmp

I'm working on one pallet in which i have to initiate hrmp channel within the code of both "mock.rs" and in the "test.rs.". Can someone please guide me through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to mock this communications to test your instructions take a look at the [XCM docs examples](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/tree/main/examples).
It has an example of how to mock a [Relay Chain runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/simple_test_net/relay_chain.rs) and a [parachain Runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/simple_test_net/parachain.rs), and it uses the [XCM Simulator](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/xcm/xcm-simulator) to setup the environment for testing.

```rs
use xcm_simulator::{decl_test_network, decl_test_parachain, decl_test_relay_chain};

decl_test_parachain! {
    pub struct ParaA {
        Runtime = parachain::Runtime,
        XcmpMessageHandler = parachain::MsgQueue,
        DmpMessageHandler = parachain::MsgQueue,
        new_ext = para_ext(1),
    }
}

decl_test_parachain! {
    pub struct ParaB {
        Runtime = parachain::Runtime,
        XcmpMessageHandler = parachain::MsgQueue,
        DmpMessageHandler = parachain::MsgQueue,
        new_ext = para_ext(2),
    }
}

decl_test_parachain! {
    pub struct ParaC {
        Runtime = parachain::Runtime,
        XcmpMessageHandler = parachain::MsgQueue,
        DmpMessageHandler = parachain::MsgQueue,
        new_ext = para_ext(2),
    }
}

decl_test_relay_chain! {
    pub struct Relay {
        Runtime = relay_chain::Runtime,
        XcmConfig = relay_chain::XcmConfig,
        new_ext = relay_ext(),
    }
}

decl_test_network! {
    pub struct MockNet {
        relay_chain = Relay,
        parachains = vec![
            (1, ParaA),
            (2, ParaB),
            (3, ParaC),
        ],
    }
}
```